# Return NULL instead of permission was denied on the column error

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with privileged data that is restricted using column level
permissions. I would like to have single query that returns data from the
table. If the user has permission, it should return the data but return
NULL if the user does not have permission.

The sa grant this privilege:

```
use WorkDB
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.[User](Name)  TO [Ali];  
go
```

Ali want to run this code:

```
SELECT [ID],[Name] FROM [WorkDB].[dbo].[User]
```

the error:
The SELECT permission was denied on the column 'ID' of the object 'User', database 'WorkDB', schema 'dbo'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible.

SQL Server won't allow the column to be referenced in the `SELECT` list unless the user has permissions on it.

I had some hope that [this approach for a missing column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/66755/3690) might work but unfortunately it doesn't.

SQL Server still resolves the column to the base table and complains about the missing permissions rather than resolving it to the same named column in the outer query.

Instead of denying column level permissions on the table you could just deny all select permissions on the table and create a `VIEW` instead. Then have all `SELECT` access go through that. With a `CASE` expression checking username/role memberships. For example

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vUser
AS
  SELECT CASE
           WHEN USER_NAME() <> 'Ali'
             THEN [ID]
         END AS [ID],
         [Name]
  FROM   [dbo].[User]
```

The view will need to have the same owner as the table for ownership chaining to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    USE master
GO

CREATE DATABASE SecurityTest;
GO

-- Creates the master key.
-- The key is encrypted using the password "23987hxJ#KL95234nl0zBe."  
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '23987hxJ#KL95234nl0zBe'; 
GO


SELECT * FROM sys.symmetric_keys WHERE name = '##MS_DatabaseMasterKey##';
GO

USE SecurityTest;
GO
CREATE CERTIFICATE CertificateSecurityTestDb
WITH SUBJECT = 'Encrypted Data';
GO

-- Create symmetric Key

CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKeySecurityTestDb WITH ALGORITHM = AES_128 ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE CertificateSecurityTestDb;
GO

CREATE TABLE TblTestTable(id int NOT NULL, CustomerFullName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, Price int DEFAULT(0),PriceEncrypted VARBINARY(500))

INSERT INTO TblTestTable(id,CustomerFullName,Price)
VALUES
(1,'ibrahim Sezen',100),(2,'Gözde Özarpacı',200),(3,'Vedat Kürkçü',300),(4,'Kaan Özdemir',50),(5,'Sema Kocabekirler',70)

GO

-- Opens the symmetric key for use
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKeySecurityTestDb
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE CertificateSecurityTestDb;
GO
UPDATE TblTestTable
SET PriceEncrypted = EncryptByKey (Key_GUID('SymmetricKeySecurityTestDb'),CAST(Price AS varchar))
FROM TblTestTable;
GO
-- Closes the symmetric key
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKeySecurityTestDb;
GO


-- Test 
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKeySecurityTestDb
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE CertificateSecurityTestDb;
GO
-- Now list the original ID, the encrypted ID 
SELECT id CustomerFullName, Price ,PriceEncrypted,
CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByKey(PriceEncrypted)) AS 'Sifresiz Kagit Maliyeti'
FROM TblTestTable

 -- Close the symmetric key
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKeySecurityTestDb;
GO


--CREATE USERS

CREATE USER [DomainName\dummyuser] FOR LOGIN [DomainName\dummyuser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[db_datareader]
GO
CREATE USER [DomainName\ogulcanc] FOR LOGIN [DomainUser\ogulcanc] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[db_datareader]
GO

-- Grant Dummy User ...
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON Certificate::CertificateSecurityTestDb TO [DomainName\dummyuser];
GO
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SYMMETRIC KEY::SymmetricKeySecurityTestDb TO [DomainName\dummyuser];
GO
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SYMMETRIC KEY::SymmetricKeySecurityTestDb TO [DomainName\dummyuser];
GO



-- Test 2
EXECUTE AS USER  = 'DomainName\ogulcanc'
GO
BEGIN TRY
    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKeyTestDb
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE CertificatetestDb;

    SELECT id CustomerFullName, Price ,PriceEncrypted,
    CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByKey(PriceEncrypted)) AS 'Price DecryptByKey'
    FROM TblTestTable

    -- Close the symmetric key
    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKeyTestDb;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    SELECT id CustomerFullName, Price ,PriceEncrypted,
    CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByKey(PriceEncrypted)) AS 'Price DecryptByKey'
    FROM TblTestTable

END CATCH

GO

REVERT;

-- TEST 2 
-----------------
-- Test 2
EXECUTE AS USER = 'DomainName\dummyuser'
GO
BEGIN TRY
    OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKeySecurityTestDb
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE CertificateSecurityTestDb;

    SELECT id CustomerFullName, Price ,PriceEncrypted,
    CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByKey(PriceEncrypted)) AS 'Price DecryptByKey'
    FROM TblTestTable

    -- Close the symmetric key
    CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKeyTestDb;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

        SELECT id CustomerFullName, Price ,PriceEncrypted,
        CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByKey(PriceEncrypted)) AS 'Price DecryptByKey'
        FROM TblTestTable

END CATCH

GO
```